# insert data through third table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

I have 3 models (Client, User and Admin) without controllers

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :username, :user_id, :client_id
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :user
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name
    has_many :admins
    has_many :users, :through => :admins
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name, :email
    has_many :admins
    has_many :clients, :through => :admins
end
```

So when I'm doing

```
u = User.first.clients.new(name: 'First Client')
u.save
```

Then everything works fine

```
(0.2ms)  begin transaction SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "clients" ("name",
"created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "First
Client"], ["created_at", "2015-12-27 10:38:47.790787"], ["updated_at",
"2015-12-27 10:38:47.790787"]]    (98.3ms)  commit transaction  =>
true
```

but when i try to see

```
2.2.2 :130 >   User.first.clients
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1   Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "admins" ON "clients"."id" = "admins"."client_id" WHERE "admins"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]] => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

So how do I insert data into third table?
I have googled a lot about this but no solution as the complication here is that the third table `Admin` also has it's mandatory column `Username`.
Also how do I insert data into `User` and `Client` table through this `Admin` table.

Comment: If you check the logs, you can see that when you save a new Client, it will only create `Client` record but not the `Admin` record. Whereas the search query is looking through `Admin` table and can't find any records.

Try something like: `c = Client.create(name: "name")` and then `User.first.clients << c`

Comment: Yea thanks for the reply @Kkulikovskis I have already tried what you said but in this the problem is when i do this it give me and error of Username can't be blank which is in admin model and when i try to provide username as well then it says unknown attribute 'username'

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't notice the username field. Well in that case I don't see any other way other than just creating each of them seperately. e.g.

`c = Client.new(name: name);   u = User.first; Admin.create(username: username, client: c, user: u)`

Comment: nups not working it just says begin transaction rollback transaction And Client.first.users is still #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: my bad. client object was not persisted to the database. Check my answer and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

I know I already stated this in the comments, but it should definitely work:

Since the `Admin` model has validation for `username` it won't be possible to simply add `client` to a `user.clients` collection, since it will result in an ActiveRecord::Validation error.

Instead you should do these steps seperately or create a method that would do them all at once:

1. Make a user object: `user = User.create(name: "name", email: "email@email.com")`
2. Make a client object `client = Client.create(name: "name")`
3. Make an admin object `admin = Admin.create(username: "username", user: user, client: client)`

this will create the necessary table entries so when you check `user.clients` it will look for all entries in `admins` table where `user_id = user.id` and then retrieve all the corresponding clients.

If you are doing this in the console, after doing all the steps do a reload on your user instance to see the clients:
`user.reload.clients`

To keep your code more organized and do all of these steps at once, you could wrap this in a user instance method. For example:

**for User Class**

```
def add_client(client_name, admin_username)
  client = Client.create(name: client_name)
  admin = Admin.create(username: admin_username, client: client, user: self)
end
```

Comment: thanks this is working but instead of creating seperately can you state a way to create this in a simple single way as that would be easy for me when I will make controllers for this.

Comment: @MalwareSkiddie Glad to help :) Please be so kind and mark the answer.

Comment: I can't as I don't have sufficient reputation for doing this. Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score
Sorry for that :/

Answer (score 0):

When you create client like this `u = User.first.clients.new(name: 'First Client')`
It insert row and write column only `name, created_at, updated_at`

And when you call `User.first.clients` like this,
It find admins that User.first has. and then find clients by admins.

So, there are no admins that have relation with client that you created first.

You should set admin_id(this column maybe exist in clients table) when create client, like this

```
user = User.first
client = user.clients.create(name: 'xxx')
user.clients << client
```

Comment: This is not entirely true, since `has_many through` should take care of that without explicitly stating the admin_id.

Comment: `...clients.new(...)`, there is no a `new()` method in `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`  relation array, only `build`.

Comment: @Kkulikovskis No, How activerecord determine which admins id choose when create new client? User has many admins and code not specify admin_id, Have you tried in console?

Comment: @Зелёный `#new` and `#build` both possible

Comment: oh, my bad, it's aliases.

Comment: @JaehyunShin If I would have to specify admin_id in Client and User model then I should not be using has_many :through as it is in it's documentation that has_many :through takes care of this itself

Comment: @MalwareSkiddie you can check empty admin table. I updated answer. If you want to many to many, I recommend `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Comment: @JaehyunShin this isn't working coz of validations. this is simple but the validations for Username in third table(Admin) is creating a mess here.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your question one by one

> 1: So how do I insert data into third table

As mentioned in the [official document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

**4.3.1 Methods Added by has_many**

> When you declare a has_many association, the declaring class
>   automatically gains **16 methods** related to the association:

```
collection<<(object, ...)
```

In your case

```
u = User.first.clients.new(name: 'First Client')
```

It should be

```
clients = User.first.clients
client = Client.new(name: 'First Client')
clients << client
```

> The collection<< method adds one or more objects to the collection by
>   setting their foreign keys to the primary key of the calling model.

---

> 2: User.first.clients How this works

```
collection(force_reload = false)
```

> The collection method returns an array of all of the associated
>   objects. If there are no associated objects, it returns an empty
>   array.

Hope this help you to proper understanding !!!